# How to call the user-extensions.js in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, user-extensions.js

I need to use the functions defined in user-extensions.js.We are in a process of migration from RC to webdriver. I came to know, that  there is JavascriptExecutor which will replace runScript and getEval.But how will i specify the user-extensions.js file.
Is it same as java -jar selenium-server-standalone.jar -userExtensions user-extensions.js?

Comment: shd i click on up arrow next to the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They now have an interface called IJavaScriptExecutor that can be used to replace user extensions.

This is the C#/NUnit version.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
long tableRowCount = (long)js.ExecuteScript("return $('#tableid tr').length);
```

Here is the Java/JUnit version:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Object o = js.executeScript("return '123'");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But, in my application, there is js file loaded with 100's of functions. Should i write each function through JSExecutor.What should i do, to re use those functions?

Comment: Are you performing other commands (ie: doStore) inside of those functions?  If so, that won't work.  You need to isolate each command to a given line in your object oriented code now with this ExecuteScript method (unless I find some documentation online proving me incorrect).  I've looked everywhere myself.  An alternative would be to write a class that contains all your functions and just get constants (or static methods if your do* functions/commands had parameters) for your scripts passed to ExecuteScript.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, after 2 years and 2 months I found a solution to use user-extensions file in webdriver and now we are migrating to webdriver.

```
 loadjsFile(driver);
```

Function is below:

```
public static void loadjsFile(WebDriver driver){
String scriptSrc = "http://localhost:8080/test/user-extensions.js";
String injectScript = "var script = document.createElement(\"script\");";
injectScript += "script.src = \""+scriptSrc+"\";";
injectScript += "script.setAttribute(\"type\",\"text/javascript\");";
injectScript += "document.body.appendChild(script);";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(injectScript);
}
```

Comment: Can I disable JavaScript on Chrome using this function? Some like this `loadjsFile.doDisableJavascript(driver);`

Answer (score 1):

There is not a way to inject javascript that is available through your test run like Selenium RC, here is a thread about some possible migration tips: http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-developers/browse_thread/thread/15cb4b774b734cc7/c7baf10db0bc2bc0